# Xcode error when merging branches related to xcschememanagement.plist

Tags: xcode, git

I am trying to merge a development branch into master and I keep getting an error involving `xcschememanagement.plist` that reads: `The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.` I have already created a `.gitignore` file, as well as navigating to the file locations in terminal and running `git rm --cached xcschememanagement.plist`

Here are some screenshots of what I am seeing:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you provide the xcschememanagement.plist file? If the data is correct, you will not encounter such error.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem, you can locate xcschememanagement.plist, right click--->OpenAs---->SourceCode to find where the error happens and fix it. But you should always edit the info.plist with Open As > Property List to avoid messing up.